# Duplicate a file with random probability

Tags: bash, files, quoting, random

I have a directly full of images and I am trying to put together a script/command that will randomly copy (with some probability) the image to a location with a random name at that destination (because I might just want to copy it in place and not collide with the existing file). Also complicating matters is that the file has spaces in it and I have 30 gb of files I am working with

Here is what I have so far. Those file spaces are a killer

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(find pics/ -type f);  do
        v=$(($RANDOM % 2))
        if [ $v -eq 0 ]; then
                cp $i dups/$RANDOM.jpg;
        fi
done
```

I would eventually like something like:

> ./rcp.sh source/ destination/

I have looked at

> shuff

but it doesn't get me past my space-in-file name issues either. Maybe there is a way to take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615524/for-loop-and-files-with-spaces) and have it also do the shuffle?

Comment: Do read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to handle files with spaces is to use the `-print0` directive for GNU find, and the `-d` option for bash's `read` command. It's also imperitive to quote the `"$variable"`

```
find pics/ -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd "" filename; do
    v=$((RANDOM % 2))
    if (( v == 0 )); then
        cp "$filename" dups/$RANDOM.jpg
    fi
done
```

The `IFS=` and `-r` bits are to ensure that spaces and backslashes are handled properly by the `read` command.

Inside `(( ... ))` arithmetic expressions, you can give shell variables without the `$`.

Comment: I made a change to account for $RANDOM only producing a 5 digit number. That space isn't large enough to ensure no collisions

Answer (score 2):

```
RAND_FILE=$( find pics/ -type f -print0 | shuf -n 1 -z )
# TODO check that RAND_FILE actually got a file, e.g. what
# if pics/ dir is empty, what happens?
cp "$RAND_FILE" ...
```

Though hard linking the copy would save space if it's on the same filesystem and the duplicate file will not be modified.

Comment: That only gets 1 random file. I need it to go through the whole dir

Comment: Oh, I was tricked by the "the image" and "a file" singular case. Use the $RANDOM version (though, what happens due to the birthday paradox?).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Glenn's input, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
    mkdir -p $2 
fi

find $1/ -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd "" filename; do
    v=$((RANDOM % 4))
    if (( v == 0 )); then
        cp "$filename" $2/`uuidgen`.jpg
    fi
done
```

I added

> uuidgen

because $RANDOM didn't supply a large enough number space to eliminate collision. One way to make this script better would be to use a number as probaility percentage and not simply as a fraction of 1/n (only 1/n numbers will be $RANDOM % n == 0)